# How to allow the user to keep entering lottery numbers until user decides to stop or end program. (In C Programming)

Tags: c

Here is my code. I tried to use  do while loop but the program exits before I even enter a character. I want the user to enter 'f' if he is finished entering, then I proceed to check if his lottery ticket number matches the winning number, or enter 'e' to end program, otherwise continue entering a number (or 'c' to continue  entering number).

```
// TestDesktop.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void canYouPlay(); //declaring the functions
void enterNum();
void keepPlaying();

int main()
{
  printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");  //welcome interface to user
  printf("                     WELCOME TO TAIWAN LOTTERY           \n");
  printf("--------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

  canYouPlay(); //calling function that checks if user can play
  enterNum(); //once user understands how to play then the enter number
  keepPlaying();

  printf("Don't be nervous you may be a winner!!\n\n\n");

  return 0;
}

//function to check if user knows how to play the game
void canYouPlay() {

  char yes_no_ans;

  printf("Have you played Taiwan Lottery before? \n\n");//if user is playing for the first time a basic game play will
                                                             //be displayed, otherwise the program will proceed to starting
                                                             //the draw.
  printf("Please enter lower case y for 'yes' or lower case n for 'no' \n\n");
  scanf(" %c", &yes_no_ans);

  if (yes_no_ans == 'y') {

    printf("\n");
    printf("Ok, great! We will now proceed to play!!\n\n");
  }

  else if (yes_no_ans == 'n') {

    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("Here are the rules for you to read: \n\n");
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    printf("Big Lotto is a lotto-type game. You must choose 6 numbers from 1~49 to place a bet.\n");
    printf("When the lottery is drawn, the lottery unit will randomly draw six numbers plus a special number.\n");
    printf("This set of numbers is the winning number of the lottery, also known as the 'prize number'.\n");
    printf("Among your six numbers, if there are more than three (including three numbers) matching the\n");
    printf("six numbers drawn in the current period (special numbers are only applicable to the second prize,\n");
    printf("the fourth prize, the land prize and the seventh prize), it is a winner. And can redeem bonuses in accordance with regulations.\n\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n\n");

  }

  else {

    printf("ERROR!!!\n\n");

  }
}


void enterNum() {

  int ticketNum, ticketNum1, ticketNum2, ticketNum3, ticketNum4, ticketNum5;

  printf("It's time to enter your ticket number: \n\n\n");
  scanf("%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,", &ticketNum, &ticketNum1, &ticketNum2, &ticketNum3, &ticketNum4, &ticketNum5);

  if (ticketNum5 == 0) { //if last digit is a zero the system shows error.

    printf("Your last digit CANNOT be a 0\n\n");

  }

  if (ticketNum > 49 || ticketNum1 > 49 || ticketNum2 > 49 || ticketNum3 > 49 || ticketNum4 > 49 || ticketNum5 > 49) {

    printf("ERROR! Your numbers MUST  be less than or equal to 49.\n\n");
  }

}


void keepPlaying() {

  char playAgain;

  do {
    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Do you want to continue entering a number?\n");
    printf("If you want to continue, enter LOWERCASE 'c' and if you are finished inputting lottery numbers enter LOWERCASE 'f'/n ");
    printf("or you can enter 'e' to exit");
    scanf("%c", playAgain);


    if (playAgain == 'c') {
      enterNum();
    }

    else if (playAgain == 'f') {

      printf("Now we will match your number to the winning number!!!!\n\n");
      //proceed to enter winning number
    }

    else if (playAgain == 'e') {
      printf("Hope you want to play longer next time!!! :)\n\n");
    }
  }

  while (playAgain != 'e');
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Don't use scanf() to read a single character

Comment: `scanf `needs to get `&playAgain` - & ALSO you can use `getchar(void)`-->`PlayAgain = getchar(void);`

Comment: This scanf: scanf("%c",playAgain); needs to be scanf("%c",&playAgain); You should have seen at least a warning on that when you compiled.

Comment: Also, the appropriate [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) format specified for `int` is `%d`, not `%u`. Either change the format specifier or change your `ticketNum`s to `unsigned`.

Comment: Don't use scanf.  If you're going to use scanf, you *must* *always* check the value it returns.  Always.  If you write `scanf` and it's not on the right hand side of an assignment or in an `if` condition, it's a bug.

Comment: When reading single `char` with scanf, use pointer: `scanf("%c", &playAgain)`

Comment: regarding the comment: `TestDesktop.cpp `  This says the program was written in C++, however, all the header files, I/O, etc are from C,

Answer (score 0):

compiling the posted code results in:

```
gcc -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11 -c "untitled2.c" -o "untitled2.o" 

untitled2.c: In function ‘enterNum’:

untitled2.c:69:11: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   69 |   scanf("%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,", &ticketNum, &ticketNum1, &ticketNum2, &ticketNum3, &ticketNum4, &ticketNum5);
      |          ~^                   ~~~~~~~~~~
      |           |                   |
      |           unsigned int *      int *
      |          %u

untitled2.c:69:14: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   69 |   scanf("%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,", &ticketNum, &ticketNum1, &ticketNum2, &ticketNum3, &ticketNum4, &ticketNum5);
      |             ~^                            ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |              |                            |
      |              unsigned int *               int *
      |             %u

untitled2.c:69:17: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   69 |   scanf("%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,", &ticketNum, &ticketNum1, &ticketNum2, &ticketNum3, &ticketNum4, &ticketNum5);
      |                ~^                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 |                                      |
      |                 unsigned int *                         int *
      |                %u

untitled2.c:69:20: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   69 |   scanf("%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,", &ticketNum, &ticketNum1, &ticketNum2, &ticketNum3, &ticketNum4, &ticketNum5);
      |                   ~^                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    |                                                |
      |                    unsigned int *                                   int *
      |                   %u

untitled2.c:69:23: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 6 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   69 |   scanf("%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,", &ticketNum, &ticketNum1, &ticketNum2, &ticketNum3, &ticketNum4, &ticketNum5);
      |                      ~^                                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                       |                                                          |
      |                       unsigned int *                                             int *
      |                      %u

untitled2.c:69:26: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 7 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
   69 |   scanf("%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,%u,", &ticketNum, &ticketNum1, &ticketNum2, &ticketNum3, &ticketNum4, &ticketNum5);
      |                         ~^                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                          |                                                                    |
      |                          unsigned int *                                                       int *
      |                         %u

untitled2.c: In function ‘keepPlaying’:

untitled2.c:94:13: warning: format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
   94 |     scanf("%c", playAgain);
      |            ~^   ~~~~~~~~~
      |             |   |
      |             |   int
      |             char *

untitled2.c:94:5: warning: ‘playAgain’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   94 |     scanf("%c", playAgain);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Compilation finished successfully.
```

Also note:  *Compilation finished successfully.*  when there are warnings, only means the compiler made some guesses, not that the correct code was produced.

When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.   ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=C11` )

Comment: Thanks! I will be more cautious to look out for these warnings. Appreciate the help!